# Import different sets of modules in main and in worker processes

Tags: python, python-import, python-multiprocessing

Is it possible, when using the multiprocess module, to get a Process to import a different library? For example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import pprint
import sys
import threading

from Foo import Moo

class Worker(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Worker Init"
        mp.Process.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print "Worker Running"
        self._static_method()

    @staticmethod
    def _static_method():
        print "I'm a-static, get it?"

class TouchWorker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TouchWorker, self).__init__(name="Touchoo" + " TouchWorker")

    def run(self):
        print "Touchoo Running"

class Parasite(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Parasite Init"
        mp.Process.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print "Parasite Running"

class Encapsulator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        workers = []

        for _ in range(4):
            wrk = Worker()
            workers.append(wrk)

        for someWorker in workers:
            someWorker.start()

        par = Parasite()
        par.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    enc = Encapsulator()
```

I only really need the 'Foo' module in the 'Worker' and 'Parasite' processes. Is it possible to get them to import that module when they run?

Comment: I changed my answer a number of times because I kept thinking of different ways this could effect different operating systems. ultimately the best answer is "don't", but if you have to, make sure you test extensively on whatever system you need this to run on. Windows and *nix systems will almost definitely operate differently in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply reverse the idiom needed to prevent infinite loops of process creation..

```
# this should look familiar
if not __name__ == "__main__":
     from Foo import Moo
```

You may find however it's easier to make your library load faster and just do it in the main file in order to avoid all sorts of ridiculous scoping issues. This may be realized by requiring a separate `Moo.initialize()` call once the subprocess starts, but it would need to be executed by each child process because memory is not shared.

A good general rule of thumb is that libraries should do no actual work on import so that they are loaded quickly. Once you call a function or class from said library, the necessary work is then performed.

Comment: Won't this break in UNIX? With `fork()`, the program isn't going to be run from the beginning again.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev yes it will.. I initially had the import inside an `__init__` method, but that comes with it's own set of broken side effects.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev the real answer is to make imports quick and light enough that even in windows where they truly are completely re-imported, the speed / memory usage of just importing is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

To spawn child processes, `multiprocessing` uses `fork()` in UNIX and running the program with special parameters in Windows that invokes special code trying to emulate the same behavior.

So, when your child processes are created, they aren't actually initialized again, all the modules that the parent loaded are already loaded for them, too.

So, if you wish to import a module:

- in master but not in workers:

  - not possible, and there's completely no need to. All you can do is to make the variables referencing the modules not visible to workers somehow
- in worker(s) but not in master:

  - `import` it inside worker function(s)

    - the import will be done in each worker, or
  - `import` it in master

    - import will be done once, in master, and children will automatically inherit it, or
  - `import` it in master, then `del` the resulting variable (so that it doesn't pollute the master's namespace), then `import` in workers again (that will reuse the existing module object from `sys.modules`)